# How to get the value of a textbox in another page (php)

Tags: php

i have  a function for creating 'textbox' in php

```
function txtbox($capt,$tname,$defvalue,$readonly='')
{
            print "<table><tr><td align=right width=300><font color=black>$capt :</td><td align=left><input type='text' name='txt'  $tname value='$defvalue' $readonly></td></tr></table>";
}
```

and called the function like:

```
txtbox('Courid','courid','');  where 2nd parameter is the name of the text box.
```

Could anyone please tell me how to get the values of the above text box in another page????

Comment: You need to put it in a form and submit the form. The textbox value will be passed by GET or POST. Second option is to use an AJAX request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the text box values in a cookie. Just make sure the data has been properly sanitized, maybe using the htmlentities() method, before setting it in the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to wrap your `input` in a `form` with a submit button. Then in your php script you will be able to get the variable at the next page refresh (i.e. when the form is submitted):

In the html:

```
<form action="name_of_your_script.php" method="POST">
    <input type='text' name='txt' value='$defvalue' $readonly>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

(replace name_of_your_script.php by the actual name of your php file)

In your php script you can get the `txt` input field like this:

```
$entered_text = $_POST['txt']
```

You could also use the `GET` method, which passes the form values through the URL, just replace POST by GET in both example if you want.

[More information about forms](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

And do not forget to sanitize all the values submitted to avoid any security problem!

Comment: $txtfine=$_GET['txtfine']; then echo $txtfine. but it is not working........................

Comment: What is txtfine? You have to use the input filed _name_ (in your code the field name is 'txt')

Comment: txt refers to the function textbox(since the value is entered in a textbox) and fine refers to the name of the textbox FINE

Comment: Yeah ok, but you can only get a form value by using the $_POST or $_GET array with the correct input field name. Considering your code, your input field name is 'txt', so you have to do $_POST['txt'] or $_GET['txt'] depending on the method used.

Comment: i understand.... bt if the function is called more than one time then is it possible to use the name 'txt' for each text field???

Comment: You won't be able to have multiple input fields with the same name. You will have to rename them dynamically for example txt1, txt2, etc or use a form array by using the following field name: name="txt[]". Then on the php side you will get an array of values. But you will have to wrap all the fields in one FORM. It depends if you want one form submitting all the fields or multiple forms to submit fields one by one.